Avoid some modules in mvn package
I have monorepo with some apps and pom.xml. I want to be able to build just specified modules in Dockerfile.
Project structure is:
pom.xml
- app-core (this is runnable app)
  - pom.xml
- app-common (this is just common classes)
  - pom.xml
- app-crawler (this is second runnable app)
  - pom.xml

Main pom.xml has all apps as modules.
app-core and app-crawler have dependencies of app-common.
Now I have such Dockerfile for app-crawler:
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY app-core/pom.xml app-core/pom.xml
COPY app-common/pom.xml app-common/pom.xml
COPY app-crawler/pom.xml app-crawler/pom.xml
RUN mvn --no-transfer-progress dependency:go-offline
COPY app-core/src app-core/src
COPY app-common/src app-common/src
COPY app-crawler/src app-crawler/src
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build /app/app-crawler/target/*.jar application.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]

If I do not copy all modules and build whole project, I see exception that some modules are not found.
Child module /app/app-core of /app/pom.xml does not exist

But this Dockerfile does not look good, because in case of new module added, I need to update all Dockerfiles.
My question is how to build only app-common and app-crawler modules without copying all other.
I tried to avoid copying whole project by using flags:
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY app-common/pom.xml app-common/pom.xml
COPY app-crawler/pom.xml app-crawler/pom.xml
RUN mvn --no-transfer-progress dependency:go-offline -am app-common app-crawler
COPY app-common/src app-common/src
COPY app-crawler/src app-crawler/src
RUN mvn package -DskipTests -am app-common,app-crawler

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build /app/app-crawler/target/*.jar application.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]

This still shows exception of not found module app-core

If you like to build inside the container you have to put everything you need to build inside the container otherwise that can not work... The question is also: Is it required to build inside a Container? Also why using an old Maven version?

@khmarbaise I use this version because this Dockerfile has been created some time ago. I get your point about building, but it seems to me a bit redundant, because some packages are not needed to build other packages

You have to copy everything into your container... multi stage container build otherwise your build will not work... If you build outside the container you will get a single result which can be copied later to the container... most of the time easier to handle...
